# Problem with click once deployment?

Tags: .net-3.5

I want to deploy .net application through clickonce. This application has the reference to another application one application. So I need to deploy two application in a single clickonce. I'm able to add another application (exe file) but unable to add the config file for the same. So how to add the config file to the clickonce deployment?

Answer (score 0):

I created a piece of software called ClickOnceMore that should be able to help you with this. It allows you to deploy any files to the target system. You can read more about it, download and trial it here: www.clickoncemore.net. I hope it helps!